# to put the final machinery in motion

Tags: meaning

I'm translating this sentence:

> Tired as he was, he grabbed up his hat and started off **to put the
>   final machinery in motion** to wind up the long chase for the firebug.

Is it just to start an engine of a car? If yes, why "final"? 
Please, help me understand this phrase. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, any complicated plan.

Comment: "To put the machinery in motion" means to start carrying out any complicated plan; *final* here presumably means the last part of the plan.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations!